# c# sql anywhere via odbc text formatting umlauts (öäü)

Tags: c#, odbc, sqlanywhere

I access an any-sql-database via odbc with c#. When i select some textvalues from the database, the umlauts (ö,ä,ü) dont get displayed correctly. I was looking here https://www.connectionstrings.com/ for a way to pass a formatting via connectionstring, but i couldn't find anything.

Do i have to convert the strings with c# after receiving them from the database? How can i do so in c#? Or is there maybe a way i can tell my connection to auto-format it correctly?

Here is a codesnippet

```
var connectionString = "Driver={SQL Anywhere 17};Host=localhost;Server=myserver;db=mydatabase;uid=dba;pwd=sql;trusted_connection=yes;";

using (var context = SqlContext.Create(connectionString, SqlProvider.AnySql))
{
    foreach (var dataRow in context.ExecuteReader("SELECT NAME FROM PERSON"))
    {
         var name = dataRow.Get<string>("NAME");

         Console.WriteLine(name); //Output is "G÷ppel" isntead of "Göpel"
    }
}
```

---

The database i am working with, is from a customer. He has a program which uses the database. When i use SQL Center to look up the data, it says "G÷ppel" too, but when the customer uses his program to work with the datbase it says "Göppel".

---

I tried to use charste=utf8 (and cp437) in my connectionstring, but there is no difference. My connectionstring looks like this now 
`"Driver={SQL Anywhere 17};Host=localhost;Server=myserver;db=mydatabase;uid=dba;pwd=sql;trusted_connection=yes;charset=utf8"`

SQL Center says, the datatype of the column is varchar.

Comment: When you look at the database table directly what do you see?

Comment: i added some info to the question

Comment: 1. try adding `charset=utf8` in your connection strng. 2. Make sure the db field is using `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: I tried the charset, but it makes no difference. The datatype of the field is varchar

Comment: What (human) language does the customer use? What operating system?

Comment: It's german. The operating system is Win7.

Comment: In IBM PC US codepage, (CP437 or IBM437) the character *÷* is `F6` = 246. In Unicode or Windows Latin1 codpage, *ö* is `F6`, and *÷* is `F7` = 247. Because ODBC and SqlCenter agree, I think what is stored byte 246, and the column is CP437. I suspect that ODBC is performing the conversion correctly, and the original application is *not* so it has stored incorrect data.... What library does the original application use?

Comment: Though it could be the other way about I guess.

Comment: I'd guess *ü* becomes *ⁿ* and *ä* becomes *Σ*

Comment: Try charset = cp437 see if that fixes it.

Comment: Unfortunately i have no clue. I do not own the original application. It was written many years in the past. The developer and the sourcecode is not available anymore. I cant even tell which language it was written in. All i have is the database.

Comment: charset=cp437 doesnt work. Is there a list of available charsets? so i can try them all?

Comment: Is it a requirement that the old application continue to work? Or are you converting the database?

Comment: No requirement. But i have to mention, that the customer has hundreds of databases in the same format. So it would be nice if i can implement a solution into my databaseconverter and do not have to change every column in every database before i can convert it.

Comment: Good luck then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the right characterset via query. `SELECT DB_PROPERTY('CharSet')` It told me that the characterset is `imb850`. I tried to pass the characterset via connectionstring, but this didn't help. So I had to Encode the string i recieved from the database.

Here is the Extensionmethod for IDataRecord i use:

```
public static T Get<T>(this IDataRecord dataRecord, int ordinal, T defaultValue)
{
    //Here i call my default generic extensionmethod
    T value = DatabaseAccessLibrary.Extensions.IDataRecordExtensions.Get<T>(dataRecord, ordinal, defaultValue);

    //Here is the extracode
    if (value != null)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            //If the value is not null and typeof string, i encode the value with the characterset
            string correctedValue = Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("ibm850").GetBytes(value.ToString()));

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(correctedValue, typeof(T));
        }
    }            

    return value;
}
```